# Can a grouping Key for <IGrouping<string, ItemsCollection>> be modified such that it is appended with a group count info for binding?

Tags: c#, linq, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

The following query returns Type `<IGrouping<string, ItemsCollection>>` which can be bound to a GridView. Used with `CollectionViewSource`, the Key (as a group name) is used to show a group header/title, say by binding to a TextBlock in `GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate` for GridView.

```
var query = from ItemObj in ItemsObjCollection
orderby ItemObj.ItemName
group ItemObj by ItemObj.GroupName into groups
orderby groups.Key
select groups;
```

All is working fine as expected and no problem so far.

My next attempt (where I find difficulty) is for the Key, which outputs a group name to also provide the group item count, such that it would be modified, for example, as "Group Name [count]" where count can be readily obtained as groups.Count() in the query. Suppose `ItemsObjCollection` represents Fruits, then the header output is desired to be like Apples [10], Bananas [7], Oranges [12], and so on.

Can a grouping Key, for the purpose of output display (via binding), be modified such that it is appended with a group count info as described? Basically, I would like `Key = $"{groups.Key} [{groups.Count()}]"` but don't know how within the query. Tried along the line of:

`select new { Key = $"{groups.Key} [{groups.Count()}]", Items = groups };`

but my modified Key doesn't show up in the binding, so didn't get far. I also find that is not straight-forward to create an instance of `IGrouping` (because it's an interface) and hoping there is a clever way to do it within a query statement above, and someone must have done this already.

Comment: You are combining a string and an integer so try this : select new { Key = groups.Key + groups.Count().ToString(), Items = groups };

Comment: That is not it. I am just using the latest string interpolation syntax of C#6.0 so what you say and what I say are equivalent. See the $" {var} ..." which is the string interpolator.

Comment: Your query is ok. How is the binding?

Comment: I have no problem with the binding, rather with getting the query result with  a modified grouping Key. Problem now solved. Than you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it but may not be neat. Basically I created an equivalent of a new query based on the above query result, but with the grouping Key modified as desired. For this, I needed a new class to create new groupings.

```
public class NewGrouping<TKey, TElement> : List<TElement>, IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
}
```

Next, a new grouping was formed by iterating the old grouping -- in the process with the Key modified with additional info as `Key = $"{grp.Key} [{grp.Count()}]"`.

```
List<IGrouping<string, ItemsObjCollection>> newQuery = new List<IGrouping<string, ItemsObjCollection>>();

foreach (var grp in query)
{
    NewGrouping<string, ItemsObjCollection> newGroup = new NewGrouping<string, ItemsObjCollection>() { Key = $"{grp.Key} [{grp.Count()}]" };
    newGroup.AddRange(grp.ToList());

    newQuery.Add(newGroup);
}
```

Use `newQuery` instead of `query` for binding to GridView, and voila! Works as expected.

PS: I wonder why someone voted-down my question as being less useful/researched. This is not a trivial question and perhaps that person didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's already there `group.Count`.